Пагинация по куплетам песни Postgres
Как реализовать пагинацию по куплетам при получении текста песни?
Мой запрос:
builder := sq.Select(
        "s.id",
        "s.song",
        "s.text",
        "g.name",
    ).From("songs AS s").
        Join("groups_songs AS gs ON s.id = gs.song_id").
        Join("groups AS g ON gs.groups_id = g.id").
        Where(sq.Eq{"s.song": name}).
        Where(sq.Eq{"s.deleted_at": "IS NULL"}).
        OrderBy("text").PlaceholderFormat(sq.Dollar)
    q, args, err := builder.ToSql()


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

А что именно то? Делаете таблицу "куплеты" (не знаю как это будет по-английски) там id песни, номер куплета и текст куплета.

@CrazyElf, спасибо)

@CrazyElf, подскажите, пожалуйста, вот у меня есть text Text c текстом, как мне его сохранить в такую таблицу  = разбить по куплетам?

А как выглядят куплеты? Возможно, там строка лишняя между ними? Тогда регулярным выражением разбить. Но как это на уровне БД сделать я не очень понимаю, я в БД мало программирую.

Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL? Пункты 5 и 3.

@CrazyElf, еще раз большое спасибо Вам!!!
